# Input from terminal into C file

Tags: c

I want to take user input from terminal and then take that input from terminal and write into a new file. 
In this I am using `usage[]` for showing my C programme's syntax
file is as:
http://pastee.co/VP10OH

```
#include "common.h"

/* system headers */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "bio.h"

/* interface headers */
#include "vmath.h"
#include "nmg.h"
#include "rtgeom.h"
#include "bu.h"
#include "raytrace.h"
#include "wdb.h"

static const char usage[] = "Usage: %s Camera x1 y1 z1 look_at x2 y2 z2 Light x3 y3 z3 -o output_file brlcad_db.g object(s)\n";
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  bu_setprogname(argv[0]);
  int c;

  while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "ClL")) != -1) 
   {
    switch (c) 
    {
             case "C":           
                 printf("camera{<%s", argv[1], ",", argv[2], ",", argv[3], ">}");
        break;
         case "l":           
                 printf("camera{%s", argv[4], ",", argv[5], ",", argv[6], "}");
        break;
         case "L":           
         printf("light {%s", argv[7], ",", argv[8], ",", argv[9], "}");
                 break;
             case 'o':           /* Output file name */
                 /* grab output file name */
                 break;

             default:
                 bu_exit(1, usage, argv[0]);
                 break;
         }
     }
}
```

but I am unable to take input from user (something is missing in file and also I am confused that where to give open file command?)
and write it into a new file.
After running `make file_name`, it gives errors as:

[image: http://ctrlv.in/363829]

Please also explain what this means and how to debug it:

```
error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=pedantic]
```

Comment: You should tell more about your operating system, C compiler, optimization flags. And it is better to put some of your code in the question (not as link to a temporary URL).

Comment: Please paste the errors into the SO question, not into some external web site where they're only available as an image file.  Also, it helps to include the command line that triggers the error messages.  The 'mixed declarations and code' message means you have a variable definition (or declaration) after executable code, a feature that was in C++ for a long time before it was added to C99.  Apparently, you've set the compiler to compile in pedantic C89/C90 mode, and you are not allowed to do that.  Simplest: use C99 or C11 mode.  Next simplest: don't add declarations after executable code.

Comment: The `case "L":` and similar statements should be using single quotes: `case 'L':`.  The constants after `case` need to be integer values; a string is not an integer.  Also, please review MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or 
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names (and links) for the same basic idea.  There is a lot of unnecessary code in what you pasted.  Especially the headers…

Answer (score 0):

You probably are using the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler. By default `gcc` is accepting [C90](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C90_%28C_version%29#C90) standard code.

You want to compile with

```
gcc -Wall -g -std=c99
```

to ask GCC to emit almost all warnings, debug information, and to accept the [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) language standard.

BTW, you might be interested in the [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) function, and you could consider (if coding on Linux) to use [GNU readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html) or [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) libraries.

If using [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) consider editing your `Makefile` (perhaps a `CFLAGS=` line) or regenerating it (e.g. passing better arguments to `./configure` for projects using `autoconf`, or running again `cmake` in some better way, etc...)

Comment: I am running make command for compiling it as per given instructions by BRL-CAD community. User give input as g-xxx C 1 2 3 l 2 3 4 L 3 4 5 file_name1 file_name2 objects. How to pass this user info into my file?

Comment: Consider also asking to the BRL-CAD community you are referring to.